# Group by code and not null columns or over(partiton in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server DB, I have a table of values that I am interested to group

when i doing a

```
min(PDM_Objective) over(partition by PDM_Objective)
```

but never turn into a group

So, the table I have its this

```
CODE|PDM_Objec  |Real_Market|Card_Market
----|-----------|-----------|---
1   |   52.99   |NULL       |NULL
1   |   NULL    |223947.00  |NULL
1001|   44.44   |NULL       |NULL
1001|   NULL    |220519.99  |NULL
```

To turn in this

```
CODE|PDM_Objec  |Real_Market|Card_Market
----|-----------|-----------|---
1   |   52.99   |223947.00  |NULL
1001|   44.44   |220519.99  |NULL
```

Comment: are you looking for max() in a group by without over() clause

Comment: Is the `Real_Market` value always the row below? Or is it possible that `CODE` `1001` can have 3 rows?

Comment: Can you attach complete query?

Comment: yes, its posible to `Real_Market` have 3 rows or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (CODE INT, PDM_Objec DECIMAL(4,2), Real_Market DECIMAL(8,2), Card_Market INT);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1   ,52.99, NULL     , NULL),
(1   ,NULL , 223947.00, NULL),
(1001,44.44, NULL     , NULL),
(1001,NULL , 220519.99, NULL);

SELECT CODE, MAX(PDM_Objec), MAX(Real_Market), MAX(Card_Market)
FROM @T
GROUP BY CODE;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/HYX26822)**

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I needed and never try ;)

Comment: @SimonRestrepo Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
select CODE
,sum(isnull(PDM_Objec,0))PDM_Objec 
,sum(isnull(Real_Market,0))Real_Market
,sum(isnull(Card_Market,0))Card_Market
from table 
group by CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

```
select CODE, sum(isnull(PDM_Objec,0)) PDM_Objec, 
sum(isnull(Real_Market,0)) Real_Market, max(Card_Market) Card_Market
from yourtable group by CODE
```